# How can I avoid the use of this nested while loop with a SQL query execution inside it?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, loops

I have to retrieve certain data from those tables, which im doing correctly(I think), but the method I achieved it with, is extremely slow and probably bad programmed, I did this just for me so making a well-looking code isnt the priority, but it have to run in a "normal" time, not like now that it runs in 10-15seconds ~ .

Here's my code:

```
$arr1=[];

$sqlquery="Select codart,canped,codpro 
           from gcpedl 
           where gcpedl.numped in (
                                   select numped 
                                   from gcpedc 
                                   where texto like '".$_POST['codobra']."'
                                   )";
$query_execute = mssql_query($sqlquery);

while($query_result=mssql_fetch_array($query_execute)){
    $arr1=$query_result;
    $sqlq="Select distinct alart.codart,pultcomp,alart.codpro 
           from alart,gcpedl 
           where gcpedl.numped in 
                 ( select numped 
                   from gcpedc 
                   where texto like '".$_POST['codobra']."') 
                     and alart.codart in 
                        (Select codart 
                         from gcpedl 
                         where numped in 
                             ( select numped 
                               from gcpedc 
                               where texto like '".$_POST['codobra']."')) ";
    $sqlex =mssql_query($sqlq);

    while($sqlre=mssql_fetch_array($sqlex)){
        if (    trim(strtoUPPER($sqlre['codart'])," ")==trim(strtoUPPER($query_result['codart'])," ") 
            and $sqlre['codpro']==$query_result['codpro'] )
        {
            if (    $arr1['codart'] != 'CUADRO' 
                and $arr1['codart'] != 'cuadro' 
                and $arr1['codart'] != 'instalacion' 
                and $arr1['codart'] != 'INSTALACION')
            {
                $materiales= $materiales+ ($sqlre['pultcomp']*$arr1['canped']);
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit: The purpose of this code is to go through every article(codart), and take its quantity(canped) and its provider(codpro), and then loop through every article in the other table and match the codart and the provider, and take out the price(pultcomp) to multiply it with the quantity.

Edit2: To choose the articles from the first table(gcpedl) and second table(alart) I have to subselect them (or join )with that third table(gcpedc) and that where clause.

Edit3: Couldnt make it work with just only one query, the further i've go is this:

```
$arr1=[];

$sqlquery="Select  g1.codart,
                g1.canped,
                g1.codpro 
        from gcpedl as g1
        inner join gcpedc as g2
            ON g1.numped = g2.numped
        where g2.texto like '".$_POST['codobra']."'";
  $query_execute = mssql_query($sqlquery);

while($query_result=mssql_fetch_array($query_execute)){
    $arr1=$query_result;
        $sqlq="Select distinct  a.codart,
                    a.pultcomp,
                    a.codpro 
    from alart AS a
    inner join gcpedl AS g
        on a.codart = g.codart 
    inner join gcpedc g1
        on g.numped = g1.numped 
    where g.numped in (select numped from gcpedc where texto like '".$_POST['codobra']."') ";
    $sqlex =mssql_query($sqlq);

    while($sqlre=mssql_fetch_array($sqlex)){if (trim(strtoUPPER($sqlre['codart'])," ")==trim(strtoUPPER($query_result['codart'])," ") and $sqlre['codpro']==$query_result['codpro'] ){
        if ($arr1['codart'] != 'CUADRO' and $arr1['codart'] != 'cuadro' and $arr1['codart'] != 'instalacion' and $arr1['codart'] != 'INSTALACION'){
$materiales= $materiales+ ($sqlre['pultcomp']*$arr1['canped']);}
```

I finally solved it, it was just that I was too asleep, the queries could be converted to just 1 query and the execution time was dramatically reduced.

```
Select gcpedl.codart, (gcpedl.canped*alart.pultcomp) as precio, alart.codpro from alart,gcpedl where gcpedl.numped in (Select numped from gcpedc where texto like '".$_POST['codobra']."') and alart.codart=gcpedl.codart and alart.codpro=gcpedl.codpro
```

Comment: you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and pretty much anytime you're doing nested queries, and the inner query uses data from the outer query, you should rewrite as a single `join`ed query.

Comment: You don't use anything from the first query in the second. Do you really need to run it everytime?

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: the sql injection attacks aren't a problem in this scenario thats why im not working around it, and i've been searching how to join those querys but i've not been succesfull

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid them using proper JOIN statements.

```
$sqlq="Select distinct  a.codart,
                        g.pultcomp,
                        g1.canped,
                        a.codpro 
        from alart a
        inner join gcpedl g
            on a.codart = g.codart 
        inner join gcpedc g1
            on g.numped = g1.numped 
        where g.texto like '".$_POST['codobra']."' and g1.texto like '".$_POST['codobra']."' ";
```

Give them a try.

Comment: this is working as the original code(as intended) but its also that slow, the problem is that im working with a query that is executing in every loop of the first while, and I have to find a solution where I dont have any sql queries executions inside a loop.

Comment: Then check if there are proper indexes on your tables. There must be indexes on `codart` and `numped` columns. Also you use `LIKE` if you pass something like this `'%some_word%'` (wild card search) you may get very slow performance on a large tables.

Comment: And for what purpose you loop inside first query?

Comment: I do not use wild cards in the LIKE statement, about indexes i dont think thats the problem, but im not so good with indexes.

Comment: The purpose of this code is to go through every article(codart), and take its quantity(canped) and its provider(codpro), and then loop through every article in the other table and match the codart and the provider, and take out the price(pultcomp) to multiply it with the quantity, im editing this on the main post.

             Edit: To choose the articles from the first table I have to subselect them (or join with that third table).

Comment: Try to use one query for that purpose. I changed my answer, please check.

Comment: Also you can multiply what you need and put a filter on SQL server side and then just fetch final results. Maybe you should post samples of data, and what output you need to get from SQL server.

Comment: I be live you can use only second query, that will be enough.

Comment: Check out my answer, try to fetch from this query

Comment: the problem is that i dont have pultcomp in table g and I dont have canped in table g1

Comment: And were do you have them? Just fix it, I believe canped is is in g1 and pultcomp in a